# How to write a property in System verilog assertions?

Tags: system-verilog, verification, formal-verification, system-verilog-assertions

I want to write a property in SVA to formally verify a behavior.

Here is what I want to:

```
property prop1(sig1,sig2,sig3,sig4);
    @(posedge clk)
    $fell(sig1) ##[1:$] first_match($fell(sig2)) ##0 sig3 |-> sig4 == sig3;
endproperty
```

How can I rewrite the above property so that after sig1 falls, it stays LOW during remaining Evaluation cycles?

Note: I do not want to put sig1 as disable iff (sig1)

Comment: Is "after sig1 falls, it stays LOW during remaining Evaluation cycles" part of the _precondition_ or the _condition_? In other words, do you want to check that sig4==sig3 _if_ sig1 stays low OR do you want to _check_ that sig1 has stayed low as well as checking sig4=sig3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
property prop1(sig1,sig2,sig3,sig4);
    @(posedge clk)
    (!sig1) throughout (##[1:$] first_match($fell(sig2)) ##0 sig3) 
          |-> sig4 == sig3;
endproperty
```

See section **16.9.9 Conditions over sequences** in the 1800-2012 LRM

Comment: Thanks! One more query: how can i extend this property to verify the consequent/satisfying sequence over 16 consecutive cycles (sig4 == sig3)[*16]  ?
Also while making sure sig1==1'b0;

Comment: You can use **throughout** in the consequent as well, but in a simple case, you can just do `( !sig1 && sig4 == sig3)[*16]`

Comment: In the above case, if sig1 is a primary input then the tool will try to find a counterexample where sig1 is 1'b1. I tried using "throughout" in consequent, but not with success. 
Can i try something as below?
(!sig1) throughout (##[1:$] first_match($fell(sig2)) ##0 sig3 
          |-> sig4 == sig3)

Comment: You don't need my permission to try any code. :) Isn't that what I suggested in my original answer? Formal tools may have some additional coding rules that I am not aware of.

Comment: :-) sorry for that rather silly comment. I have already tried that. Formal Tools always try to find a Counter example for the consequent. Since sig1 is Primary Input, i cannot put it as mentioned(). Thanks anyways:)